Coccinelle doesn't make any changes
I have tried the following:
jaca@DESKTOP-PLDN4P1:~/dev/spatch_test$ cat spatch_test.cocci
@@
expression E1, Fmt;
@@

- MY_MACRO(E1, M_OK, Fmt)
+ MY_MACRO2(M_OK, E1, Fmt)

jaca@DESKTOP-PLDN4P1:~/dev/spatch_test$ cat test.c
MY_MACRO(myVar1, M_OK, ("%d my strings", myVar2))

jaca@DESKTOP-PLDN4P1:~/dev/spatch_test$ spatch --sp-file spatch_test.cocci --dir ./test.c -o ./test2.c
init_defs_builtins: /usr/local/lib/coccinelle/standard.h
HANDLING: ./test.c

jaca@DESKTOP-PLDN4P1:~/dev/spatch_test$ cat test2.c
MY_MACRO(myVar1, M_OK, ("%d my strings", myVar2))

jaca@DESKTOP-PLDN4P1:~/dev/spatch_test$ spatch --version
spatch version 1.2-00008-g75525032 compiled with OCaml version 4.08.1
Flags passed to the configure script: [none]
OCaml scripting support: no
Python scripting support: yes
Syntax of regular expressions: Str

I even tried:
@@
@@

- MY_MACRO(myVar1, M_OK, ("%d my strings", myVar2))
+ MY_MACRO2(myVar1, M_OK, ("%d my strings", myVar2))

but with no result either. The console snippet above is from WSL Ubuntu on which I've built coccinelle from sources, but I also tried the same on redhat with package installation:
spatch version 1.0.7 compiled with OCaml version 4.05.0
Flags passed to the configure script: --build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --program-prefix= --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --sysconfdir=/etc --datadir=/usr/share --inludedir=/usr/include --libdir=/usr/lib64 --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --localstatedir=/var --sharedstatedir=/var/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-python=/usr/bin/python --with-menhir=/usr/bin/menhir
OCaml scripting support: yes
Python scripting support: yes
Syntax of regular expressions: PCRE

What am I doing wrong?

Turned out source file has to have "proper" C syntax because coccinelle parses C into AST before applying transfromations.
I can't see the workaround which is sad because my original problem was related to some UT code, which does not meet the standards needed.
